# When I switch my laptop it is opening as terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, python, uninstall, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4. I had uninstalled python3 but after sometime it getting stuck so I restarted it via power off button. But now it is opening as terminal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqTfy.jpg)

Comment: Basically you removed the desktop. If you can still login and `sudo apt install {desktopyouwant}` still works it will restore it but I doubt it. Use a live session, boot from it and reinstall Ubuntu ---not picking format when setting up your partitions---.

Comment: It got stuck because python is fundamental part of the OS, never uninstall. Now probably the easiest way is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 was likely a dependency for your desktop environment, when you removed Python3 it would have removed any dependent software.

Reinstall your desktop environment:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal`

If you want all the additional software like Libre Office then instead run this:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Reboot once the command completes.